# How To Add Fragment Dynamically Using Navigation Component

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I need to add another fragment in a fragment dynamically and runtime using navigation component. it is certain that I need to write code in dynamically added fragment. How can I do that?

Comment: Is it in your graph? Do you want to add it in a fragment by fragmentManager or via navigation component. Provide more info about this situation.